# How to save certain values during recursion in java without passing them as a parameter

Tags: java, recursion

So I've been practicing for an exam and this is one of the questions that came up. I have to write a recursive method that finds the max Sum of Opposite numbers in an array.
(So add the first number with the last in the array, then the second with the second last....)
For example if I have the array {2,2,4,5}, the answer would be 7.

The problem is that I don't have a way to save my highest sum, I'm not allowed to pass another parameter for it. The only parameters I'm allowed are the array in which the numbers are saved, the start index and the end index.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private static int findMaxOppositeSum(int[] sequence, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sequence[start] + sequence[end] + findMaxOppositeSum(sequence, start + 1, end - 1);


}
```

Comment: you can return the biggest value between `sequence[start] + sequence[end]` and `findMaxOppositeSum(sequence, start + 1, end - 1)`

Comment: What would happen if you used `Math.max()` in the final `return` statement in the method you've presented?

Comment: Just curious what you do if the array has an odd number of values?  Do you add the middle to itself or does the assignment implicitly require and even sized array?

Comment: or does it use zero instead of the middle element (posted code)?

Comment: the examples given to us only have even sized ones

Comment: examples tend to not cover all possible use cases...the specification is important... (and based on my experience here, the examples from some competitive sites seems to intentionally avoid some border cases that are used in the actual (hidden) tests)

Comment: BTW, instead of returning `0` you need to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` when `start >= end`. You could have some or all negative values. If the max is negative, your method will return 0 every time. So you need to return the smallest possible value you could get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the max value. You just need a little change your return statement. This will recursively return the maximum value of the opposites, starting from the inside and working its way to the edges.

```
return Math.max(sequence[start] + sequence[end], findMaxOppositeSum(sequence, start + 1, end - 1);
```

Comment: I did not think Math.max would take previous calls into account. Thank you very much, I feel kinda stupid for not thinking of something so simple...

Comment: @Frag Math.max does NOT take the previous calls into account! Why do you think so? It just accounts for the *actual* values and the result of the next recursive call.

Comment: I misunderstood then, i thought that it would have to since its given me the max out of all the previous calls, but it just compares the highest to the next  from what I understand now.

Comment: maybe you should use a debugger to see how the recursive calls works. (the first call will max the sum of first and last and the result of the second call; the second call has no information about the previous sum (and does not need it) it just sums the second first/last and max it with result of the next call;... basically resulting in `max([0]+[n-1], max([1]+[n-2], max([2]+[n-3], ...)))` where each max corresponds to one call deeper)

Comment: alright will do, thanks for taking the time to explain it